# weird spacing with \, and and babel

Tags: spacing, xetex, babel

When using XeLaTeX and babel "francais", I sometimes get weird spacing: e.g. \, makes a wider space than the regular space (see what happens on the second line here).

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text,Numbers={OldStyle},Ligatures={Common},Contextuals=Alternate]{Garamond Premier Pro}

\newcommand{\teng}[1]{\emph{#1}}

\begin{document}
\noindent (par exemple Z3 de Microsoft ou Yices de SRI)\,; ce dernier donne une solution qui correspond à une trace d'exécution menant de la précondition à une des postconditions dont on désire déterminer l'accessibilité (par exemple, des conditions d'erreur comme la division par zéro).
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you use \, before ;? The babel option french/francais will already add space before ;.

Comment: Note: the standard way of calling `frenchb` is `\usepackage[french]{babel}` instead of `\usepackage[francais]{babel}` afaik.

Comment: That's what's supposed to happen: French babel already puts a space before the semicolon and you don't need to add manually one. Consider adopting polyglossia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`frenchb` (French for `babel`) adds non-secable normal spaces before `;`. For this reason, your `\,` is added to the space already added by `babel` (or maybe even just ignored and replaced by a normal non-secable space).

If you wish to prevent `frenchb` from adding spaces before `;`, you can do:

```
\shorthandoff{;}
```

after `\begin{document}` or

```
\AtBeginDocument{\shorthandoff{;}}
```

in your preamble.

Comment: `\,` adds a kern and the (active) semicolon "unskips", so the thin space `\,` is actually added to the space provided by `;`, because `\unskip` doesn't do anything to kerns. However this space is not a normal interword space, but slightly smaller. A normal spaces is added in front of a colon.